# Angular 5 ERROR Endpoint unreachable

Tags: angular

I am getting this error after upgrading one of my project dependencies (ngx-config). Here is the full error from the console.

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Endpoint unreachable! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Endpoint unreachable! undefined (zone.js:630)`

Note: `ng serve` works and compiles just fine, this error occurs at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is being thrown by ngx-config.

Turns out we are using `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` which depends on `HttpClient`. The newest version of ngx-config also uses `HttpClient` (instead of the old `Http`). Upon upgrading ngx-config/core and ngx-config/http-loader to version `5.0.0` there arose a circular dependency. The call to get `config.json` was now going through the interceptor but the interceptor depended upon the config settings in `config.json`. I simply added the following to the interceptor:

```
if (req.url.endsWith(".json")) {
  return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => { return })
}
```

I wish there was a way to globally add exceptions to the interceptor (black list, white list or both) but there doesn't appear to be any plan to implement such a feature https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20203.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include to your providers in app.module.ts this one:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

That's work for me